# Angular Router-Outlet disappears when resizing browser

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my app-routing.module I have a route with children. The parent component (Route) displays the router-outlet within its HTML. Like so:

```
<ng-template #thenBlock>
<div class="container-login">
    <button class="logoutBtn" (click)="navigateToLogin()">Logout</button>
    <div class="column-left"><app-sidenav></app-sidenav></div>
    <div class="column-right"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</ng-template>
```

My app-router.module: (part)

```
{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: 
    [
    {path: 'transaction', component: TransactionComponent},
    {path: 'transfer', component: TransferComponent},
    {path: 'document', component: DocumentComponent},
    {path: 'management', component: ManagementComponent}
    ]}
```

Whenever I display the component, my URL is localhost/dashboard. I then navigate to dasboard/transaction and it is shown in the router-outlet.
Now when I resize my browser window, it instantly disappears and says "router-outlet 0x0" when inspecting. No warning in the conosole.

Why does the content of the router-outlet disappear?

Comment: check your CSS. the column might be collapsing due to a media query.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this line in my component:

```
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']);
```

For detecting screen size and events being fired. Turns out that it somehow interferes with the router-outlet.. Unfortunately, I cannot elaborate the reason for this. But now it works.

Comment: this decorator needs to be immediately followed by a function. If it was not then that may be why your component was breaking.